# Need free pdf file editor software

Tags: pdf

I need a free PDF file editor, where i can easily add or delete something inside a PDF file. I have searched a lot on Google but can't find any good software for this purpose. If you know of one, please tell me.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't remember any... You could always download acrobat pro trial as a short term plan http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=acrobat_pro&loc=us

Comment: Following Joonas' mention, a trial version of Illustrator would also allow you to edit a PDF.

Comment: See [PDF editor, creator alternatives?](http://superuser.com/q/81123), [Which programs can I use to edit PDF files?](http://askubuntu.com/q/16652), [Modifying PDF files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3378)

Answer (score 2):

It'll likely depend on the complexities of the PDF, but Inkscape is open source and can open and save PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it myself, but if [CutePDF Editor](http://www.cutepdf-editor.com/) is from the same guys that developed CutePDF (the virtual printer that exports anything to PDF), it should be trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is Libre Office Draw. You can open multiple pages on it.

But keep in mind that some objects can not be edited if they are rasterized. You would need Gimp for that.

Inkscape can only open a single page.

Answer (score -1):

It's not free, but Flexipdf by Softmaker lets you extract images, change fonts, convert to other file formats. It's the only program I know of that lets you change fonts.

Comment: I down voted this because the question *specifically* asks for "free" alternatives. It's not helpful to list pay-for-play software.

Comment: I said it wasn't free.